# Excel VBA Fill cell color based on value in different cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to modify my code to only fill cells in red, if the value = 0 and the adjacent cell value in column L is empty.

For cells with a value = 0 and the adjacent cell value in column L is not empty, I would like to fill the 0 cell with a pattern.

I attached a screenshot of how it should look.

[image]

```
Sub Fill_Cell()

    Dim rngCell As Range

    For Each rngCell In Range("C7:K100")
        If rngCell.Value = "0" Then
        rngCell.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        Else
        ''If value = 0 & adjacent cell in column L <> ''
        ''rngCell.Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlGray16
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: isn't this supposed to be done with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fill_Cell()

Dim rngCell As Range

For Each rngCell In Range("C7:K100")
    If rngCell.Value = "0" Then
        Select Case Cells(rngCell.row, "L")
            Case Is = ""
                rngCell.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Case Else
                rngCell.Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlGray16
        End Select
    End If
Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Comment: @user3596788 Sure, no problem! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You are close! I would try to take your code and modify it just a bit

```
Sub Fill_Cell()

Dim rngCell As Range

For Each rngCell In Range("C7:K100")
    If rngCell.Value = "0" Then
        If Cells(rngCell.Row, 12).Value <> "" Then
            'If it is 0 and L not empty
            rngCell.Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlGray16
        else
            'If it is 0 and L is empty
            rngCell.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a couple of people have beaten me:

```
   For Each rngCell In Range("C7:K100")
        If rngCell.Value = "0" And Cells((rngCell.Row), 12).Value <> "" Then
            rngCell.Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlGray16
        ElseIf rngCell.Value = "0" Then
            rngCell.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: No problem, glad to use of use. Thanks.